# Woocommerce registeration check if referral code is valid

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am looking to add a check to my woocommerce registration form to check if a referral code exists, that is set as a custom field (repeater) in the backend. It is currently set up with Advanced Custom Fields and set on an options page. It should check if code is in the repeater fields otherwise refuse registration. The code then needs to be added to the user and shown in the user backend.

I have tried to manipulate terms and conditions code on registration but havent got anywhere. Thanks

This is my ACF code to grab the valid codes for validation.

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('referralcode', 'option') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('referralcode', 'option') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
        the_sub_field('referralvalue', 'option');

    endwhile;

else :
    // no rows found
endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

1) Add referral registration field

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_referral_registration_field', 20 );
function add_referral_registration_field() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_referralcode"><?php _e( 'Referral code', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required"> *</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="referralcode" id="reg_referralcode" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['referralcode'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['referralcode'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

2) Validate (or check) referral  registration field…

> Here you will add your repeater field code to check this referral code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'referral_registration_field_validation', 20, 3 );
function referral_registration_field_validation( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';
    $error  = '<strong>' . __( 'Error', $domain ) . '</strong>: ';

    // HERE you get the array of referral codes (to be replaced with ACF code)
    $referral_codes_to_check = array("ABCABC","DEFDEF");

    if ( isset( $_POST['referralcode'] ) && empty( $_POST['referralcode'] ) )
    {
        $validation_errors->add( 'referralcode_error', $error . __( 'Referral code is required!', $domain ) );
    }
    // HERE BELOW we check the referral code
    elseif( ! in_array( $_POST['referralcode'], $referral_codes_to_check ) )
    {
        $validation_errors->add( 'referralcode_error', $error . __( 'This referral code is not valid, please try something else…', $domain ) );
    }
}
```

3) Save referral field data

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'save_referral_registration_field_data', 20, 1 );
function save_referral_registration_field_data( $customer_id ) {

    // Referral code field
    if ( isset( $_POST['referralcode'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'referralcode', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['referralcode'] ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

---

And if you wish to display the field (and update the field) in edit user account form:

1) Edit referral registration field:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'edit_referral_registration_field', 20 );
function edit_referral_registration_field() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="referralcode"><?php _e( 'Referral code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="referralcode" id="referralcode" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->referralcode ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

2) Update referral registration field:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_referral_registration_field', 20, 1 );
function save_referral_registration_field( $user_id ) {

    if( isset( $_POST['referralcode'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'referralcode', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['referralcode'] ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: I have added an addition for Account details edit form…

Comment: Great answer!

However, the code for updating the referral registration field from user's Account details page (/my-account/edit-account/) doesn't seem to be working.

After updating the referral code and pressing Save Changes button, get the "Account details changed successfully." notice but the referral code remains the same as what user originally entered at the time of registration. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it. The function names are not matching. `save_favorite_color_account_details` should be `save_referral_registration_field `.

Comment: @SridharKatakam Yes sorry it was a little mistake (updated).